# Is there a way to trigger an action without a button click

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm about to develop an add-in that will automatically pull some data from emails and modify some fields in our database. However this extraction could be a bit error prone so we wanted a layer of human verification when it occurred.

We do this in gmail already, when the user open an email and we find something we want to extract we display a confirmation pop-up, and this feature is very well received by our clients.

I am planning on using the dialogbox but it seems to trigger this the action to display the box needs to be attached to a ui element for the user to click.

Is there any way to tigger an action pragmatically, without a users click?

Comment: Is that a JS or a COM based Outlook addin?

Comment: It is javascript

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the pinnable task pane available for Outlook add-ins, see [Implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) for more information. There you can implement the `ItemChanged` event handler. The event handler should accept a single parameter, which is an object literal. The type property of this object will be set to `Office.EventType.ItemChanged`. When the event is called, the `Office.context.mailbox.item` object is already updated to reflect the currently selected item.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    // Set up ItemChanged event
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged);

    UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox.item);
  });
};

// Example implementation
function UpdateTaskPaneUI(item)
{
  // Assuming that item is always a read item (instead of a compose item).
  if (item != null) console.log(item.subject);
}
```

Comment: So basically, if they had the task pane open I could listen for the item change event and when that is triggered I could run my logic for that email and if necessary show a pop up... its a reasonable workaround

Comment: It is unfortunate that they would have to have the task pane pinned for this to work though. Would love to be able to give this functionality without requiring the user to take up their screen space with an unnecessary pinned pane.

Comment: Eugene's answer here is correct. This is currently not possible. The Pinnable add-in is the only thing that is close, (kind of).  We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins